# Sql Server: write a query that progressively relaxes constraints

Tags: sql-server

We have a stored procedure where we want to find the best possibly match, but we want to relax some of the constraints if we don't find an initial results, so we can at least return some results.

Currently this is done by executing the same query repeatedly with a different where clause and stopping when a query returns any results. Something like:

```
select * from table where (field1 = @param1 and field2 = @param2 and field3 = @param3)
if @ROWCOUNT = then
    select * from table where (field1 = @param1 and field2 = @param2)
-- ... etc.
```

However, I don't like this approach as it means repeating the query several times, so I'd like to be able do the same thing and minimize the repetition.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM   table 
WHERE  ( field1 = @param1 AND field2 = @param2 )
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN field1 = @param1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
          CASE WHEN field2 = @param2  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
          CASE WHEN field3 = @param3  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END    
      DESC
```